# Return all matches to an item in my database using graphql

Tags: graphql

I am attempting to return all items from my database that match a specific value. The key in the database is 'category'. I am using graqphql I have written my query in my typedefs called 'nameAndLink':

```
const { gql } = require('apollo-server-express');

module.exports = gql`
  type Link {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    link: String!
    category: String!
    imageLink: String
  }
  input LinkInput {
    name: String!
    link: String!
    category: String!
    imageLink: String
  }
  input LinkUpdateInput {
    name: String
    link: String
    category: String
    imageLink: String
  }
  type Query {
    totalRecords: Int!
    allLinks: [Link]!
    image(category: String!): Link!
    category(category: String!): Link!
    nameAndLink(category: String!): Link!
  }
  type Mutation {
    linkCreate(input: LinkInput): Link!
    linkUpdate(id: ID!, input: LinkUpdateInput): Link!
  }
`;
```

I have also written the resolver as follows:

```
const nameAndLink = async (parent, args, context, info) => {
  const nameAndLink = Link.find({
    category: args.category
  });
  return nameAndLink;
};
```

However when I run the query I get a non-nullable field Link.name. Here is my full resolver file:

```
const Link = require('../models/link');

// Queries
const totalRecords = () => Link.countDocuments();

const allLinks = async (parent, args, context, info) => {
  const links = await Link.find();
  return links;
};

const image = async (parent, args, context, info) => {
  const images = await Link.findOne({
    category: args.category
  });
  return images;
};

const category = async (parent, args, context, info) => {
  const category = await Link.findOne({
    category: args.category
  });
  return category;
};

const nameAndLink = async (parent, args, context, info) => {
  const nameAndLink = Link.find({
    category: args.category
  });
  return nameAndLink;
};

// Mutations
const linkCreate = async (parent, { input }, context, info) => {
  const link = await Link.findOne({ link: context.res.link });
  return link
    ? link
    : new Link({
        name: input.name,
        link: input.link,
        category: input.category,
        imageLink: input.imageLink
      }).save();
};

const linkUpdate = async (parent, args, { req, res }, info) => {
  const linkUpdate = await Link.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: args.id },
    {
      $set: {
        ...args.input
      }
    },
    { new: true }
  ).exec();
  return linkUpdate;
};

module.exports = {
  Query: {
    totalRecords,
    allLinks,
    image,
    category,
    nameAndLink
  },
  Mutation: {
    linkCreate,
    linkUpdate
  }
};
```

Comment: eh, `[Link]` vs `Link` ... `find` vs `findOne` ... match return type to proper find

Comment: @xadm thank you! that was the issue. if you want to post it as the answer I will mark it as correct!